# Courier mail server - forward to dynamic address?

Tags: email, courier-imap

I'm running a Debian server with Courier as MTA and would like to create a mail forwarding rule that does the following:

1. extract the domain from the address of the sender

   - example: noreply@example.com
2. forward the mail to a dynamically kind of calculated address of a catch all mailbox that has the extracted domain as prefix:

   - example: example.com@mycatchallbox.com

I guess this has got be possible in some way... but how?

Comment: I think you could use Sieve for this.